# REST API iOS development

Tags: ios, rest, xcode4, restkit

I'm having lots of trouble setting up the RestKit API to my app. I wonder if there is any other good API to make RESTful apps? I've just followed lots of tutorials and the github directory of the RestKit API, but I just can't get it up and running. I've seen that Xcode 4 is having problems importing this API.

---

This is an old question, Nowadays, after 4 years in iOS development I use AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

It is quite simple to start, and can be installed using cocoapods.

Comment: Would you care to specify what particular errors RestKit integration is spewing? Most of them can be easily solved.

Comment: Hi. I'm one of the core developers for RestKit. Please describe what your exact problem with RestKit is - here or in the mailing list - and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Victor, I followed every instruction at the github, and when i tried to #import <RestKit/RestKit.h> it says there is no such file, same as with the other lib Peter suggested... But Ill try again today, Ive stayed 5,5h trying to solve these problems, I thought iOS dev wasn't so painful...

Comment: when I imported "RestKit.h" it found something, but gave me build errors inside the framework btw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest standard iOS classes such as NSURLConnection and NSJSONSerialization.

Here is a series of posts that explains how to use Blocks to asynchronously perform Http requests against a RESTful API:
http://kerkermeister.net/series/ios-and-rest-http-connections/

Comment: Considering ASI became deprecated, I use nowadays the default solution.

Answer (score 6):

I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for RESTful client stuff in my apps.

Comment: ca u use JSON parses with it ?

Comment: I tried to set up this, but it occurred many build failures, I'm googling it, maybe there are some problems with xcode 4 and ASIHTTPRequest too...

Comment: I use Xcode 4 with ASIHTTPRequest.  There are many JSON libraries as well. In my current project I am using yajl-objc http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/

Comment: You need to carefully go through the setup instructions for each of these libraries or they won't work. You will also need to post your actual errors and issues for people to be able to help you further.

Comment: I've been through all of these instructions: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/#adding_build_target_dependencies

Comment: when I try to #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" it says there is no such file or directory..

Comment: It sounds like you didn't add it or didn't include it in your target.  Start with these instructions:  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Comment: Peter, are u sure this instructions are for xcode 4 ? my xcode doesn't have a tab called "project"

Comment: I finnaly made it to import the ASIHTTP classes ... it was missing other framework dependencies... like CFNetwork and stuff... thx for helping guys

Comment: This library seems abandoned

Comment: A lot of people have moved to restkit and mknetworkkit but there are good forks, and a couple times a year it seems that they pull changes in. Personally, I'd rather have an api more like backbone.

Comment: The now selected answer regarding NSURLConnection and NSJSONSerialization is correct at this time. ASI became antiquated and built in tools got better.

Answer (score 5):

You can use rest kit api for that.
You find the details about the rest kit in followings link
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Comment: This one is more recent, and seems quite complete

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on RestKit http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial