# iOS. Is it possible to overwrite content of a remote json file or replace it with new?

Tags: ios, json, networking

I've got a `json` file on my server. How do i change its content from an `iOS` app? I need either write to it or completely replace that file with a new one. Is it even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to iOS and depends on what you understand by "remote file". Typically you'd download JSON contents with a HTTP GET request. In this case the "reverse" operation would be HTTP PUSH. You need the remote end (web service) to support this operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the below methods:

1- Use PHP to edit data in the file by sending a POST request with the changes to your PHP which handles the editing on the server.

2- Use PHP to upload the new file and replace the old one by uploading the file to your specified PHP script ([this link can help](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/)).

3- Use FTP to transfer the new file & replace the old one (you can use [this library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp) or use [Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some kind of API on a server side. Let me explain it by example:
You have a route that returns back data in json format (for example list or item reviews). For example

```
GET domain.com/api/reviews 
(it returns json file)
```

After that you working with these data and send a request to store it to your server (frequently using the same API route)

```
PUT domain.com/api/reviews 
(and put new json data inside a request body, fore example in newJsonData = "{....}")
```

Your script (for example /api/reviews.php) should support 2 kinds of request: GET and PUT. If it's get GET request it returns json data. If it's PUT then it rewrite existing json file with new data.

Read more about REST API:

[REST API iOS development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108908/rest-api-ios-development)

[Objective-C: Best way to access REST API on your iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)

Few advices:

- If you will not have any kind of authenticating on a server side it will be very easy for someone else to store dangerous data on a server using the same request
- It's very easy to add API support using AFNetworking library: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking